# 'File or directory is corrupted or unreadable' in Windows 10 only; works in 8.1/7?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I can't seem to access my external hard drive in Windows 10 systems, producing the error said in title. I tried it other Win 10 PCs to same results.

However, when I plug it on 8.1 or 7, I can access it perfectly.

I read that `chkdsk` ought to correct this, but not for me. I did try it:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Seagate Expansion Drive.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  24064 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  0 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  155 reparse records processed.
  26698 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
  155 reparse records processed.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  1318 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  300992 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 976759807 KB total disk space.
 182915900 KB in 11162 files.
      5416 KB in 1319 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    120535 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 793717956 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 244189951 total allocation units on disk.
 198429489 allocation units available on disk.
```

So it basically shows nothing out of the ordinary and is able to detect the presence of files inside. Still I can't access it on Explorer. I just don't wanna go find a 7/8.1 OS unit everytime I want something out of it. Any ideas? Thanks!